# Is it possible to find the Stack Exchange profile of Meetup participants?

Tags: support, users, meetups

I'm interested in attending the upcoming local meetup.  Is there any way to find the Stack Exchange profile for local participants?  Meetup.com doesn't seem to link the two in any way.

Comment: Hmmm, did someone make sure to tell Rebecca to leave her pointy stick at home?

Answer (score 2):

No, not really, and that's a good thing.

Programmers' regulars will probably recognize my Meetup avatar, and sharpen their knifes, but other than using the same avatar / username for both Stack Exchange and Meetup there isn't an easy way to know who's who.

Are you trying to avoid someone? ;P

Comment: I don't consider it a good thing... part of the interest is linking the online identity to a real person.  If I just wanted to meet "some programmers" there are any number of user groups and other meetups in my area.